# Rendering a sprite Java Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, sprite

I am trying to render a sprite 'chicken   chciekenImage', however when i run, the image can not be seen, however i believe the image is being rendered but just not appearing, as it overlaps with another sprite to give an output, so it is there just not showing. There are no errors.

The Code:

```
public void render(float delta) {
Iterator<Rectangle> iter = chickens.iterator();
...
while(iter.hasNext()){      
    Rectangle chicken = iter.next();
    if(farmerX < (chicken.x - 85/2)) chicken.x -= 2.5;
    if(farmerX > (chicken.x - 85/2))chicken.x += 2.5;
    if (farmerY < (chicken.y - 66/2))chicken.y -= 2.5;
    if(farmerY > (chicken.y - 66/2))chicken.y += 2.5;

    float diffYchick;
    float diffXchick;
    float angleDegreeschick;

    diffYchick = (float) (farmerY - chicken.y);
    diffXchick = (float) (farmerX - chicken.x);

    angleDegreeschick = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(diffYchick, diffXchick));

    game.batch.begin();
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Chickens Running: " + runningChickens, 0, 1080);
    game.batch.draw(chickenImage, (float)chicken.x, (float)chicken.y, (float)42.5, (float)33, (float)85, (float)66, (float)1, (float)1, (float)angleDegreeschick);
    game.batch.end();

    camera.update();
    inputUpdate(touch, camera);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
...
     }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rended image not showing Java Libgdx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784624/rended-image-not-showing-java-libgdx)

Comment: @Tenfour04 any ideas of the problem?

Comment: use a sprite to draw your texture is easier

Comment: @Paul the chicken and farmer are rectangles for the overlap detection and other things if thats what u mean?

Comment: i mean use the sprite class to draw your chicken, and .setrotation to rotate it. the sprite also has a rectangle

Comment: @Paul couldnt get if (chicken.overlaps(farmer)) to work with sprites?

Comment: You can do `chicken.bounds.overlaps(farmer.bounds);` if they are Sprites.